# How to extract empty sequence from parent in generated XSD (CXF)

Tags: cxf

I have simple test WS

```java
@WebService
public interface TestWs {

    @WebMethod
    String foo(Child child);

}
```

with a very basic implementation

```java
@Component("testWsEndpoint")
public class TestWsImpl implements TestWs {

    @Override
    public String foo(final Child child) {
        return "Ok";
    }

}
```

in generated WSDL I have

```xml
<xs:complexType name="child">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:parent">
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

which is perfectly correct, but customer asked to remove that empty `<xs:sequence/>`, probably because it causes problems in some tool they are using. Is this possible in CXF?

Additional quetion is - is it possible to force CXF to generate XSD separated from WSDL? I know that for command line JavaToWs I can simply add `-createxsdimports` parameter, but what about CXFServlet?

Comment: If you want to have control over WSDL/XSD why don't you develop it [contract-first](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html#DevelopingaService-WSDLFirstDevelopment) (i.e. start with WSDL/XSD and then generate classes)?

Comment: It's just a personal preference. I'm in phase creating new WS and while there are a lot of changes it's easier for me to maintain java classes and generate WSDL instead of contract-first approach. Request came when I sent first version, which I generated from Java classes representing model. My personal opinion is that this request is senseless, I'm just wondering if it is possible. If I'd like to use existing WS with fixed WSDL, then I'll use contract-first approach. But thanks for tip, I can try if it generates different classes.

Comment: Maybe the best would be to switch from java first approach to wsdl first approach in some stage, but I feel this is something like doing the same work twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of empty `<xsd:sequence/>` is IMHO impossible currently. It's because JAXB currently works this way. There is even a comment in [JAXB implementation](https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb~version2/trunk/jaxb-ri/runtime/src/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/schemagen/Tree.java):

> we neither have epsilon or emptySet, so can't handle children.length==0 nicely

If you prefer you can raise a bug for JAXB team. [Someone even raised this issue](https://java.net/projects/metro/lists/users/archive/2009-03/message/42) but there was no answer.

Regarding the second problem - forcing CXF to generate XSD separated from WSDL. It is possible using `org.apache.cxf.wsdl.create.imports` property. You can set it using annotation:

```
@EndpointProperty(key="org.apache.cxf.wsdl.create.imports", value="true")
```

on your interface or implementation class.

After that you will get something like:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="TestWsImplService" targetNamespace="http://server.hw.demo/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema>
            <import namespace="http://server.hw.demo/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:9000/test?xsd=TestWsImplService_schema1.xsd"/>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    ...
```

Back to my original comment I would recommend WSDL-first approach. I developed this way multiple services. Having strict interface with constraints (patterns, multiplicity) was very beneficial when two different systems were communicating. Lots of input validation was done for me without writing additional code. True - writing WSDL is not pleasant task, but once you have service definition you can easily change inputs and outputs in your XSD files.

Comment: I will try this EndpointProperty. For validations I'm using `<jaxws:endpoint id="cxfTestWsEndpoint" address="/TestWs" implementor="#testWsEndpoint"><jaxws:properties><entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" /></jaxws:properties></jaxws:endpoint>` in cxf-serlet.xml, so I'm not doing input validations for formats and required fields also ;-)

Comment: Adding another entry to properties: `<entry key="org.apache.cxf.wsdl.create.imports" value="true" />` would have exactly the same effect as @EndpointProperty annotation.

Comment: That key works as a charm :-) I was thinking about it and using WSDL-first approach solved another problem - it is not possible to have WSDL documented (it's not possible to generate WSDL comments from Java classes).